# Not able to delete lot of files at once in linux

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I have run the following command, from inside of these log folders. But it looks like each folder will take infinite time.

> find . -type f -exec rm -v {} \;

```
rwxrwxr-x  2 root     root      77881344 Mar 16 03:06 logs.123  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root     105709568 Nov 14 20:09 logs_15Nov2011  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root       6852608 Aug  1  2011 logs2  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root     286191616 Nov  2 08:40 logs_2Nov  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root      25206784 Nov 10 04:04 logs_del  
drwxrwxr-x  4 root     root       2686976 Oct  6 01:56 logs_delete  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root          4096 May 11  2011 logsMay112011  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root      69087232 Aug 29  2011 logs_old  
drwxrwxr-x  7 root     root     382480384 May  9  2011 logs.old905  
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     root          4096 May 11  2011 logsTR1218
```

Any suggestion better and faster than this to remove all these logs?

Comment: What is the type of your filesystem ?  If ext2/3/4, are you using directory indexing (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ext3#Using_Directory_Indexing) ?

Comment: This isn't an directly related to your question, but after you succeed in deleting these old logs, look into `logrotate` to avoid this problem in the future: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Answer (score 6):

GNU find has the -delete option, which is always safe:

```
find . -type -f -delete
```

As commented elsewhere, you may use xargs too, but be very careful how you use it.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -vf
```

Comment: To me from the end result both the commands looks the same. Can you please explain why with the second command, one has to be more careful, thanks.

Comment: Because without NUL-terminated filenames (strings), unexpected results may happen - something you do not want with `rm`! Consider what happens when you run "rm -rf /etc foo" - that is, deleting a directory named "etc foo", which is a perfectly valid filename. Without proper quoting, you're going to wreck your system.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers assume that you want to keep the directories, but it's not clear from your original message that you do; moreover, even if you wanted to keep the structure, you'll need to remove and recreate the directories anyway, because the directory files have become **very** large - they won't shrink when you empty them, and their size will massively slow down operations in them in future.

So have you considered just

```
rm -rf log*
```

Comment: If find -exec fails to put all the arguments on a single command-line, so will any other command - including rm.

Comment: adaptr, I agree - which is why I'm suggesting doing to the recursive rm from the parent directory, where there aren't lots of files, and the glob expansion won't break the shell.

Comment: MadHatter - I donot want to keep directories, but the command just donot respond. And at times due  to internet issues, putties close and the command exits.

Comment: It's not responding because it's got a vast amount of work to do, and it's extremely inefficient work thanks to the size of those directories.  Nevertheless, it's progressing; you should probably read the man page on the screen command and start the rm inside a screen session, this will enable to command to keep running even if your ssh session disconnects, and you can just reconnect to it once you make a new ssh session.  Or just background the job: `rm -rf log* &` .

Comment: rm -rf log* &, yes this is what we do now. Nevertheless thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  So, what's the problem?  Your unlink operations take a long time because time to perform directory operations goes roughly with thee square of the size of the directory file; in this case, you've got dir files up to 100,000 times the size of a normal dir file, so each operation will take up to ten billion times as long as it normally would.  Nothing is going to speed that up except faster disc hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage the many errors when rm fails to delete directories, you can approach the problem from the other side

```
for dir in $(find . -type d)
do
  rm $dir/*
done
```

Comment: `rm -r` will also delete *empty* directories in the given tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -type f | xargs rm -vf
```

Comment: xargs is **dangerous** when used in combination with any command that alters data. If you must use xargs, use it with safe, NUL-terminated strings instead: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -vf`

Answer (score 0):

Other than reformating the partition, I do not see any faster way to delete all the files.

The problem is that you have a huge amount of files in those directories (the size in the `ls -l` output that you provide is enormous !).  For each `rm`, the filesystem must do the following:

1. Queries the directory for [inode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/what-is-a-superblock-inode-dentry-and-a-file) number,
2. Update the directory to remove the file from it,
3. Decrements the link count of the inode (see [hard link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/why-do-hard-links-exist) if you want to know more about link count),
4. If the link count is zero, remove the data from disk.

Even if you `rm` the directory, you only get rid of the step # 2 above becasue you still need to query the directory and decrement the link count.  Querying the directory could be optimize to get more than one inode number at the time, but in all cases, for each file to delete, the filesystem must check the inode for the link count and update the inode (or mark it for deletion).

In other word, this operation is `O(n)` on the number of files to delete, which seams very large in you case.

If you cannot format your partition, which I guess is your case ;-), just launch the task in the background or in a [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) and be patient.

Another solution is to backup the files you want to keep, format the partition, and restore the files.  Maybe it can be faster than deleting all the files, but is it more time consuming (the `find...rm` can be forgot in the background for many days if needed...).